# Android combine same resolution drawable resources in one folder

Tags: android, resources, drawable

Excuse for my English. I have an app that supports 800x480, 1280x720, 1280x800 px screen resolution. Drawable resourser for 800x480 and 1280x800 is same. Question: how to combine this two resources types in one resource folder (drawable-800x480 + drawable-1280x800)